# Caesar Cipher written in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I have written a simple [Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) in Python in my efforts to learn a language that isn't C. It works much like any other Caesar implementation and takes various command line arguments to specify options such as the spacing of the output, whether to encrypt or decrypt the input, and whether or not to try and bruteforce the cipher.

This is my first ever Python program so I'm primarily looking to learn some best practices for the language as well as remove any inefficiencies or redundancies in my code.

Thanks!

```
import argparse
import re

def caesar(string, shift):
    output = ''
    for char in string:
        if char.isspace():
            output += ' '
        else:
            output += chr(((ord(char) - 65 + shift) % 26) + 65)
    return output

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Encrypt or decrpyt a string using the Caesar Cipher")

    parser.add_argument("--bruteforce", "--brute", "-b", help = "bruteforce mode", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--encrypt", "--enc", "-e", help = "encryption mode (default)", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--decrpyt", "--dec", "-d", help = "decryption mode", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--no-spacing", "--no-space", "-n", help = "no spacing in output (default)", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--preserve-spacing", "--preserve", "-p", help = "use same spacing as original string", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--shift", "-s", help = "value for the Caesar shift", type = int, choices = range(1, 26))
    parser.add_argument("--spacing", "-x", help = "specify the spacing in output", type = int)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.bruteforce:
        bruteforce = True
    else:
        bruteforce = False
        shift = args.shift

    if args.decrpyt:
        shift = -shift

    if args.preserve_spacing: 
        regex = re.compile('[^A-Z\s]')
    else:
        regex = re.compile('[^A-Z]')

    string = regex.sub('', input().upper())

    if args.spacing:
        string = ' '.join([string[i:i + args.spacing] for i in range(0, len(string), args.spacing)])

    if bruteforce:
        for shift in range(1, 26):
            print("%d: %s" %(shift, caesar(string, -shift)))
    else:
        print(caesar(string, shift))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

## The Caesar function

First the parameter `string` should be renamed as it has the same name as the standard module [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html). Sure you don't use it, but it is a bad habit to get into and can result in problems later on. Regardless, since we're dealing with cryptography and sending messages and such, wouldn't a better word be `message`?

There is also no documentation. `caesar` is not a descriptive name if you don't already know what a Caesar cipher is. You should have a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) that describes that this a Caesar cipher and at least link to Wikipedia for a description of the Caesar cipher if not describe it yourself.

## The `main` function

### `store_true`

```
if args.bruteforce:
    bruteforce = True
else:
    bruteforce = False
    shift = args.shift
```

The `'store_true'` flag indicates that `args.bruteforce` is `True` when the flag is specified *and* [`False` when it is not specified.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) Forget the `bruteforce` variable and just concern yourself with `args.bruteforce`.

### `store_const`

There is also a `store_const` action that has the optional<sup>1</sup> parameters `const` and `default`. Thus you can have `const=re.compile('[^A-Z\s]')` and `default=re.compile('[^A-Z]')`. This removes the need for:

```
if args.preserve_spacing: 
    regex = re.compile('[^A-Z\s]')
else:
    regex = re.compile('[^A-Z]')
```

<sup>1 The `const` parameter is a paradoxically optional argument that is required</sup>